# ABP UnitOfWork is not locking database record for IsolationLevel RepeatableRead

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, unit-of-work

It's better if this issue is explained with an example. I have a database table `Person` with an `int` column named `[Num]`. It has only a record with the initial value of `Num` == 0.

In my **PersonAppService.cs**, there are the following 2 methods

```
public void TestIncrementA()
{
    using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(new UnitOfWorkOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead })
    {
        var person = _personRepository.Get(1);
        person.Num += 1;

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        uow.Complete();
    }
}

public void TestIncrementB()
{
    using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(new UnitOfWorkOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead })
    {
        var person = _personRepository.Get(1);
        person.Num += 1;

        uow.Complete();
    }
}
```

The 2 methods are essentially the same which increment the value of the column `Num` by one except that the first method delays the thread.

Now in the console of a web browser, I run the following commands in quick succession.

```
abp.services.app.person.testIncrementA();
abp.services.app.person.testIncrementB();
```

I would expect the value of `Num` in my database to be **2** now since it's been incremented twice. However it's only **1**.

It's clear the `RepeatableRead` UoW is not locking the row properly. I have also tried using the attribute `[UnitOfWork(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)]` to no avail.

But, if I were to set the following in the `PreInitialize` of a module, it works.

```
Configuration.UnitOfWork.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead;
```

This will unfortunately force RepeatableRead app-wide. Is there something that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a different isolation level from the ambient unit of work, begin another with `RequiresNew`:

```
using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(new UnitOfWorkOptions
{
    Scope = TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, // Add this
    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead
})
{
    ...
}
```

## Explanation

From https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work:

> If a unit of work method calls another unit of work method, both use the same connection & transaction. The first entered method manages the connection & transaction and then the others reuse it.
>
> The default `IsolationLevel` for a unit of work is `ReadUncommitted` if it is not configured. ...
>
> #### Conventional Unit Of Work Methods
>
> Some methods are unit of work methods by default:
>
> - ...
> - All Application Service methods.
> - ...